# How to change the setup.exe details in setup & deployment project

Tags: .net, setup-deployment

I have created a setup & deployment project in .NET.

After building the project, the .msi & .exe files are created in the debug folder.

I want to change the setup.exe properties, which are currently

```
Copyright @microsoft corporation 
file version 9.0.21022.8
```

How do I change the setup.exe details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah right. Sorry I mis-understood your problem.

The answer is that you can't. The reason for this is that the setup.exe file doesn't directly install your application. The user can run Setup.exe, which checks whether the target machine has the correct version of the .NET Framework runtime installed. If not, it will prompt the user to download the runtime from Microsoft's website and install it. Once it is satisfied that the required runtime is installed, it then invokes the .msi to install the program.

So technically setup.exe is a Microsoft exe and not yours.

If you are certain that your users will have the correct version of the CLR you can get away with distributing only the .msi file

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the properties of your setup project before building.

In Visual Studio just go to the properties of the project and set "Manufacturer" and all other properties to your desired values then build. Simple.

Comment: thanks for reply , but in my project the all properies are already set these properties disply into the .msi package but not in the setup.exe package